# ¿Quienes usan voseo en Medellín?

Tags: colombia, voseo, ustedeo

Estoy intentando determinar si hay algún patrón en el uso de voseo, ustedeo y tuteo en Colombia, específicamente en la cuidad de Medellín y la region paisa.

¿Qué tipo de patron? Según clase socioeconómico, por ejemplo, o generaciones, o nivel de intimidad. Pero no he podido encontrar un patrón. El uso parece ser al azar.

He notado que la empleada que hace la limpieza siempre ustedea a su esposo, un taxista, en el teléfono. Le pregunté a ella sobre el uso de voseo y me dijo que ella misma nunca vosea pero sus niñas adolescentes siempre vosean. O sea en la misma casa hay gente voseando y ustedeando a la vez.

¿Se puede predecir si una persona va a usar voseo, tuteo o ustedeo en Medellín?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El único patrón que podría ser general sería que *usted* denota respeto mientras que *vos* denota confianza. El problema es que los paisas somos muy "confianzudos" y tratamos con confianza a quien deberíamos tratar con más respeto.

El aspecto socioeconómico y la edad no tienen influencia más allá de que en algunos casos a mayor estrato socioeconómico (o mejor, mayór nivel educativo) o a mayor edad las personas aprenden a respetar más a los demás y amplían el rango del uso de usted.

En el caso de la empleada que dice que "nunca vosea" y que trata de *usted* al marido, es posible que sea un hogar de cultura machista donde el señor taxista es "el jefe" de la casa o que ella misma es una persona de baja autoestima que siente que debe tratar como superiores a la mayoría de las personas.

En general los paisas voseamos a todo el que le tenemos confianza y ustedeamos en relaciones laborales, comerciales y con desconocidos pero como ya lo notaste es difícil predecir cuándo vamos a usar uno o el otro.

Escribiendo esta respuesta me he puesto a pensar si yo mismo soy predecible en ese aspecto e hice el ejercicio al ir a la tienda. Pregunté por un par de cosas a uno de los empleados (una persona mayor de 30 años pero no mayor que yo) y luego interactué con la empleada de la caja (una mujer joven de aprox 20 años). Con el primero lo traté de usted pero con la segunda voseé. El patrón puede ser que con el primero yo me aproximé a solicitar algo y lo traté con respeto y con la segunda ella me saludó amablemente cuando yo me acercaba a pagar y por eso la traté con más confianza.

Respecto al tuteo, solo se puede decir que es muy escaso. Algunas parejas lo usan pero no es común. De hecho a los paisas el tuteo nos suena "falso" y [salamero (*zalamero)](http://www.tubabel.com/definicion/41184-salamero-a).

Comment: Buenísima respuesta con introspección final. En España se usa _zalamero_ (con _z_) pero no tiene tan mala connotación

Comment: Si @fedorqui'SOstopharming'. Salamero con "s" parece ser otra "colombianada'. Como correctamente lo dices deberíamos escribirlo con Z. Parece ser un error generalizado en hispanoamérica [como se ve aquí también](http://diccionariolibre.com/definicion/Salamero)

Comment: El Diccionario de americanismos lo recoge, aunque solo para Paraguay: http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=salamero

Comment: @DGaleano, hasta ahora me vengo a enterar que el tuteo en la región antioqueña tiene connotaciòn de salamero. En Bogotá el asunto es variable entre el tuteo y el usted.

Comment: Genial respuesta como siempre muchas gracias @DGaleano. Entonces, un niño hablando a sus padres usaría voseo, ¿cierto?

Comment: @aris vosear a los padres sería el caso más general (e ideal) pero similar a lo que mencionas de la empleada y su marido algunas familias son más "rígidas" que otras y algunos niños le tienen confianza a sus padres y otros les tienen respeto. En mi caso yo siempre he voseado con mis padres pero no es el 100% de los casos.

Comment: @DGaleano en la situación rígida que ud. menciona ¿el padre tambien ustedea a sus niños? ¿Se usa mutuamente? ¿O solo ustedea el niño y el padre vosea al niño?

Comment: @aris Interesante pregunta e intuyes bien. En mi experiencia es tal como te lo imaginas. El niño ustedea a su padre y el padre vosea al niño.